# if my file is in directory siblings of dir Tank, how do I import Tank.py?

Tags: python

Main/
Main.py
Tanks/
**init**.py
Tank.py             <-- that is in here
BlueTanks/
**init**.py
BlueTank.py
Planes/
Planes.py           <-- want to do stuff here

im having toruble importing the tank.py file in planes.py file. I dont want to use sys

Comment: Please provide your file tree in clear and understable strusture and also what is your problem, what error do you get?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.